# How can I format bytes a cell in Excel as KB, MB, GB etc?

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a value in a cell that's in bytes. But nobody can read 728398112238. I'd rather it say 678.37GB

To write a formula to format it relatively easy (here's one: http://www.yonahruss.com/2007/02/format-excel-numbers-as-gb-mb-kb-b.html)

But is there any way to do this as a 'format'? I'd like to have the big number in the cell, but have it display as the human-readable format.

Comment: Quick note if at all you're interested in stuff like this: "kB" is standard (lowercase 'k', not upper case). Sources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo- If you aren't interested, please ignore my post :)

Comment: The link in this post is dead. Here is another link to a solution using a formula: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1063a039-f26b-4bfe-a9eb-2704ae0575dc/format-for-kbmbgbtb?forum=excel

Comment: Here's the formula

`=IF(A1>POWER(1024,4),TRUNC(A1/POWER(1024,4),2)&" TB", IF(A1>POWER(1024,3),TRUNC(A1/POWER(1024,3),2)&" GB", IF(A1>POWER(1024,2), ROUND(A1/POWER(1024,2),0)&" MB", ROUND(A1/1024,0)&" KB")))`

Comment: Wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20090306232900/https://www.yonahruss.com/2007/02/format-excel-numbers-as-gb-mb-kb-b.html  (There are currently too many pending edits so I can't change it right now)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can't really do calculations in the formatting features of Excel. You can use something like the following to do a rough estimation though:

```
[<500000]#,##0" B";[<500000000]#,##0,," MB";#,##0,,," GB"
```

Comment: Wow .. you've confirmed my suspicion that I can't do calculations .. but your solution is genius! I'll use that or something close to. Thanks!

Comment: For regional settings with ' ' as thousand-separator and ',' as comma-separator: [<500000]# ##0" B ";[<500000000]# ##0  " MB";# ##0   " GB"

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is wrong! Dividing by "5" or 500000 will convert the value to a completely different one. I used the value "569692" and this code gave me "1 MB"

Comment: Can someone explain why this uses 500,000 and 500,000,000 instead of multiples of 1,000 or 1024?

Comment: The answer I gave hints at it. Because a calculation can’t be done in the formatting (I.e. 500,000/1,000) I used 500,000 and 500,000,000 as midpoints to determine when things should be rounded to B, MB, GB. It’s a hack, and shouldn’t be used if precision is needed. 

There are other things that could be done if you need more precision (custom formulas via macros, in cell formulas, named ranges, etc)

Answer (score 72):

Here is one that I have been using: -

```
[<1000000]0.00," KB";[<1000000000]0.00,," MB";0.00,,," GB"
```

Seems to work fine.

Comment: not perfect (multiples of 1000 vs 1024), but good enough & upvoted. thanks!

Comment: Kevin: kB/MB/GB is really correct with multiples of 1000 only (as defined by SI, used by Mac & hard-drives). I guess this doesn't change that you want 1024 (more correctly written KiB/MiB/GiB, as used in Linux GUIs) so just pointing out that it's Windows that maintains this historic and confusing notation. The binary notation was standardised last century, so it's high-time they got with the program. ;-)

Comment: Or if you want bytes, KB, and MB instead of KB,MB,GB: `[<1000]#" B";[<1000000]0.00," KB";0.00,," MB"`

Answer (score 23):

The above formatting approach works but only for three levels. The above used KB, MB, and GB. Here I've expanded it to six. Right-click on the cell(s) and select Format Cells. Under the Number tab, select Custom. Then in the Type: box, put the following:

```
[<1000]##0.00"  B";[<1000000]##0.00," KB";##0.00,," MB"
```

Then select OK. This covers B, KB, and MB. Then, with the same cells selected, click Home ribbon, Conditional Formatting, New Rule. Select Format only cells that contain. Then below in the rule description, Format only cells with, Cell Value, greater than or equal to, 1000000000 (that's 9 zeros.) Then click on Format, Number tab, Custom, and in the Type: box, put the following:

```
[<1000000000000]##0.00,,," GB";[<1000000000000000]##0.00,,,," TB";#,##0.00,,,,," PB"
```

Select OK, and OK. This conditional formatting will take over only if the value is bigger than 1,000,000,000. And it will take care of the GB, TB, and PB ranges.

```
567.00  B
  5.67 KB
 56.70 KB
567.00 KB
  5.67 MB
 56.70 MB
567.00 MB
  5.67 GB
 56.70 GB
567.00 GB
  5.67 TB
 56.70 TB
567.00 TB
  5.67 PB
 56.70 PB
```

Anything bigger than PB will just show up as a bigger PB, e.g. 56,700 PB. You could add another conditional formatting to handle even bigger values, EB, and so on.

Comment: A minor note: if in an installatoin you have a locale that prescribes other separators replace the separators in the strings above with the proper ones. In my langauage , and . are swapped so I had to use: [<1000]##0,00"  B";[<1000000]##0,00." KB";##0,00.." MB" and
[<1000000000000]##0,00..." GB";[<1000000000000000]##0,00...." TB";#.##0,00....." PB"

Answer (score 13):

Though Excel format conditions will only display 1 of 3 conditions related to number size (they code it as *"positive; negative; zero; text"* but I prefer to see it as : *if isnumber and true; elseif isnumber and false; elseif number; elseif is text* )

so to me the best answer is David's as well as Grastveit's comment for other regional format.

Here are the ones I use depending on reports I make.

```
[<1000000]#,##0.00," KB";[<1000000000]#,##0.00,," MB";#,##0.00,,," GB"

[>999999999999]#,##0.00,,,," TB";[>999999999]#,##0.00,,," GB";#.##0.00,," MB"

[<1000000]# ##0,00 " KB";[<1000000000]# ##0,00  " MB";# ##0,00   " GB"

[>999999999999]# ##0,00    " TB";[>999999999]# ##0,00   " GB";# ##0,00  " MB"
```

Take your pick!

Answer (score 12):

Slight change to make it work on my region, Europe (. as thousands separator, comma as decimal separator):

```
[<1000000]#.##0,00" KB";[<1000000000]#.##0,00.." MB";#.##0,00..." GB"
```

Still same issue on data conversion (1000 != 1024) but it does the job for me.

Answer (score 11):

Because nobody wrote this answer yet I thought it would be good for future thread finders. There is an easy way to do conversions in excel for bits and byte with the conversion function.

You just need to use `=CONVERT(Number or Cell, "fromDatatype", "toDatatype")`

So for example `=CONVERT(5, "Gbyte", Mbyte")`

You can find the doc about this under Measurement sytems -> Information
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-function-d785bef1-808e-4aac-bdcd-666c810f9af2

Sadly there is no chart about the prefixes like `M`, `Mi`, `G` or `Gi`. But it's easy. Just the common prefix and then bit respectively byte.

| Prefix | Short | bit | byte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yotta | Y | Ybit | Ybyte |
| Zetta | Z | Zbit | Zbyte |
| Exa | E | Ebit | Ebyte |
| Peta | P | Pbit | Pbyte |
| Tera | T | Tbit | Tbyte |
| Giga | G | Gbit | Gbyte |
| Mega | M | Mbit | Mbyte |
| Kilo | k | kbit | kbyte |
| Hekto | h | hbit | hbyte |
| Deka | da | dabit | dabyte |
| Yobi | Yi | Yibit | Yibyte |
| Zebi | Zi | Zibit | Zibyte |
| Exbi | Ei | Eibit | Eibyte |
| Pebi | Pi | Pibit | Pibyte |
| Tebi | Ti | Tibit | Tibyte |
| Gibi | Gi | Gibit | Gibyte |
| Mebi | Mi | Mibit | Mibyte |
| Kibi | ki | kibit | kibyte |

Comment: This is great but the function is "CONVERT", not "CONVERSION".

Comment: This is the by far the best solution and has been available since Excel 2007. Further information about CONVERT including a chart https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-convert-function.html

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a way to make it show you binary gigabytes (multiples of 1024x1024x1024) but you can make it show you decimal gigabytes using a format like:

```
0.00,,,"GB"
```

Comment: I like the simplicity. Even if it is not multiples of 1,024, this answer is useful.

Comment: Multiples of 1024 would not be KB, MB, GB anyway. That would be KiB, MiB, GiB.

Answer (score 4):

Above formula requires a minus sign in the first line: "=IF(A1<-999500000000"

```
=IF(A1<-999500000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" TB"""),
IF(A1<-9995000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" GB"""),
IF(A1<-9995000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,,"" MB"""),
IF(A1<-9995,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,"" KB"""),
IF(A1<-1000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<0,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<1000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<999500,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,"" KB"""),
IF(A1<999500000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,,"" MB"""),
IF(A1<999500000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" GB"""),
TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,,"" TB""")))))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

And, yet another solution, is to use engineering notation. (That's like scientific notation except the exponent is always a multiple of 3.) Right-click on the cell(s) and select Format Cells. Under the Number tab, select Custom. Then in the Type: box, put the following:

```
##0.00E+00
```

Then click OK. Instead of K, M, etc, you'll have +3, +6, etc. This will work for positive and negative numbers, as well as positive and negative exponents, -3 is m, -6 is u, etc.

```
567.00E-06
  5.67E-03
 56.70E-03
567.00E-03
  5.67E+00
 56.70E+00
567.00E+00
  5.67E+03
 56.70E+03
567.00E+03
  5.67E+06
```

Answer (score 2):

## Less than Tera will write on GB & more than 999 GB write on TB

[<1000]0" GB";[>999]0.0," TB"

OR

[<1000]0" GB";[>=1000]0.0," TB"

Answer (score 2):

Paste this next to your values(bytes) and this will automatically change it to whatever your size of value is.

`=IF(G10>=1099511627776,CONCATENATE(ROUND((G10/1024/1024/1024/1024),1)," TB"),IF(G10>=1073741824,CONCATENATE(ROUND((G10/1024/1024/1024),1)," GB"),IF(G10>=1048576,CONCATENATE(ROUND((G10/1024/1024),1)," MB"),IF(G10>=1024,CONCATENATE(ROUND((G10/1024),1)," KB"),IF(G10>=1,CONCATENATE((G10)," BYTES"),0)))))`

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here supply values with powers of 10. Here is a format using proper SI units (multiples of 1024, i.e. Mebibytes, Gibibytes, and Tebibytes):

```
[>1099511627776]#.##,,,," TiB";[>1073741824]#.##,,," GiB";0.##,," MiB"
```

This supports MiB, GiB, and TiB showing two decimal places.

Comment: You are dividing by a power of 10. MiB, GiB, and TiB means 1024^2, 1024^3, 1024^4.

Comment: @Sam you probably missed the answer for you comment.

Comment: No, @Sam is correct. This answer correctly uses 1024 multiples as conditions, but the formatting is still 10-based.

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately this is not possible with simple formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I use CDH hadoop and when I export excel report, I have two problems;

1) convert Linux date to excel date,
For that, add an empty column next to date column lets say the top row is B4,
paste below formula and drag the **BLACK "+"** all the way to your last day at the end of the column. Then hide the original column

```
=(((B4/1000/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970|1|1)+(-5/24)
```

2) Convert disk size from byte to TB, GB, and MB
the best formula for that is this

```
[>999999999999]# ##0.000,,,," TB";[>999999999]# ##0.000,,," GB";# ##0.000,," MB"
```

it will give you values with 3 decimals
just format cells --> Custom and paste the above code there

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a "brute force" but works ;)

```
=IF(E4/1000<1;CONCATENATE(E4;" bps");IF(E4/1000<1000;CONCATENATE(ROUND(E4/1000;2);" kbps");IF(E4/1000000<1000;CONCATENATE(ROUND(E4/1000000;2);" mbps");IF(E4/1000000000<1000;CONCATENATE(ROUND(E4/1000000000;2);" gbps")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

For the exact result, I'd rather calculate it than using display format.

Assuming A1 cell has value 29773945664927.

1. Count the number of commas in B1 cell.

   =QUOTIENT(LEN(A1)-1,3)
2. Divide the value by 1024^B1 in C1 cell.

   =A1/1024^B1
3. Display unit in D1 cell.

   =SWITCH(B1, 5," PB", 4," TB", 3," GB", 2," MB",1," KB",0," B")
4. Hide B1 cell.

> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqnjO.png)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the answers here just improved on this formula to have decimal places on bigger values and cater for negative values.

```
=IF(A1<999500000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" TB"""),
IF(A1<-9995000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" GB"""),
IF(A1<-9995000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,,"" MB"""),
IF(A1<-9995,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,"" KB"""),
IF(A1<-1000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<0,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<1000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0"" B """),
IF(A1<999500,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,"" KB"""),
IF(A1<999500000,TEXT(A1,"#,##0,,"" MB"""),
IF(A1<999500000000,TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,"" GB"""),
TEXT(A1,"#,##.#0,,,,"" TB""")))))))))))
```

Comment: The original question included details on using a formula. But it's about using a number format. Your solution is very similar to the linked one except you deal with negative numbers. Rather than include them in separate IF statements, use ABS() to get the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a lot of the answers here are outdated, as I did not get the expected result from the given answer.

If you have value in KB that you would like to format according to the size, you can try the following.

---

#### Formula

`[<1000]#" KB ";[<1000000]#0,00 " MB";0,##  " GB"`

---

#### Initial Value (in KB) => Output

`952` => `952 KB`

`1514` => `1.51 MB`

`5122323` => `5.12 GB`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on one cell. Lets say cell `F3`, you can use this:

```
=IF(F3<(1024), F3 & " B", IF(F3<(1024*1024), QUOTIENT(F3,1024) & " KB", IF(F3<(1024*1024*1024), QUOTIENT(F3,(1024*1024)) & " MB", IF(F3<(1024*1024*1024*1024), QUOTIENT(F3,(1024*1024*1024)) & " GB", IF(F3<(1024*1024*1024*1024*1024), QUOTIENT(F3,(1024*1024*1024*1024)) & " TB", "H")))))
```

This has been tried on google sheets.
IF ELSE caluse might need modifications

Answer (score 0):

I like the last version shared but I wanted share the version for French Excel.

I have replaced QUOTIENT by a ROUND function, to have some digits after the decimal point, because that is what I need:

```
=SI(
   F3<1024; F3 & " B"; 
      SI(F3<(1024*1024); ARRONDI(F3/1024;2) & " KB"; 
          SI(F3<(1024*1024*1024); ARRONDI(F3/(1024*1024);2) & " MB";
               SI(F3<(1024*1024*1024*1024); ARRONDI(F3/(1024*1024*1024);2) & " GB";
                    SI(F3<(1024*1024*1024*1024*1024); ARRONDI(F3/(1024*1024*1024*1024);2)& " TB"; "H")
               ) 
           )
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

My goto formula for this after many years of refinement is the [here](https://gist.github.com/carrgilson/a3d243985ed4a118ca045d43a76d9649).

You can use the beginning variable definitions to define aspects of the conversion:

- **cell** defines the cell containing the bytes to format
- **cell_style** defines if you're using the R1C1 (*rowcolumn*) or the A1 (*alphanumeric*) cell reference style
- **unit_type** defines if you want the resulting output calculated to a *binary* or *metric* value

```
=LET(

README_,"This formula formats a byte count, rounding it to its significant digit and to two decimal places, applying the appropriate unit of measurement",

README1,"Adjust the below [variable] definitions to your need, where the viable options are (bracketed)",
README2,"[cell]       specify the individual cell address containing the byte count to format, this should be contained within double quotation marks",
README3,"[cell_style] define if you're using the R1C1 (rowcolumn) or the A1 (alphanumeric) cell reference style",
README4,"[unit_type]  define if you want the resulting output calculated to a base 2 (binary) or base 10 (metric) value",

CONSTANTS,"Do not alter these",
binary,1024,
metric,1000,
rowcolumn,0,
alphanumeric,1,

VARIABLES,"Adjust these to your need",
cell,"RC[-1]",
unit_type,binary,
cell_style,rowcolumn,

IF(N("Error if the speficied cell is not a number")+
NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(cell,cell_style))),"#MISSINGNO",

IF(unit_type=1000
+N("Calculate the result at base 10"),

IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^8),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \Y\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^7),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \Z\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^6),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \E\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^5),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \P\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^4),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \T\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^3),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \G\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^2),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000/1000),"#,## ????.00 \M\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1000^1),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1000),"#,## ????.00 \K\B"),
IF(INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)=1,
"1 B",TEXT(INDIRECT(cell,cell_style),"## ????0 \B")
))))))))),

IF(unit_type=1024
+N("Calculate the result at base 2"),

IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,80)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,80)),"#,## ????.00 \Y\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,70)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,70)),"#,## ????.00 \Z\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,60)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,60)),"#,## ????.00 \E\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,50)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,50)),"#,## ????.00 \P\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,40)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,40)),"#,## ????.00 \T\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,30)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,30)),"#,## ????.00 \G\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=POWER(2,20)),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/POWER(2,20)),"#,## ????.00 \M\i\B"),
IF((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)>=1024),
TEXT((INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)/1024),"#,## ????.00 \K\i\B"),
IF(INDIRECT(cell,cell_style)=1,
"1 B",TEXT(INDIRECT(cell,cell_style),"## ????0 \B")
)))))))))))))
```

If you ever want to do the reverse, and derive [a rough raw count of bytes from a pre-formatted value](https://gist.github.com/carrgilson/cfbad6e63894bb671410c19697837d23), I've got a formula for that too.

Comment: If you can comment the "algorythm" you implemented, would be great.

Comment: @RobyB, challenge accepted, I've found that commenting inside of Excel formula is 'interesting'. I've tried to lay my code out clearer, adding comments and usage where I can. The meat of the code borrows from others here, where the value falls through a list of comparisons, stopping at best unit.