# Calculation with values expressed in different units (KB, MB, GB)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, array-formulas

I am looking for a simple way in Excel to calculate with units of different values. I have a list of several values in `KB`, `MB` and `GB` and I want to get a calculated output in `GB`.

Here's a piece of the list:

```
66.0 MB
570 KB
1.10 GB
2.21 KB
```

Output: ??? GB.

All values are in the same row (C) with B/KB/MB/GB behind the value.

Comment: Are the units in a separate column or the same?

Comment: @xQbert The units are in the same column :-) I can alter this if necessary.

Comment: @Bartdude I have no programming experience in Excel, hence the question here :-) 
Sorry guys, excel noob with a deadline :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533811/2258 shows a similar question related to formatting.

Comment: @pnuts > Thanks for pointing this out. That said, apparently it is also acceptable for OP to show no efforts in this specific case. indeed, the same kind of question in any other programming language would have been closed very quickly...

Comment: Yay.. Downvote something just because you think the question is stupid.
Downvote to you for thinking ur better then others and giving unconstructive input.

Comment: @RemyvanTour > I don't think your question is stupid and never said anything so. But I'm sure it is against SO principle that OP should show minimal research effort in their questions. As SO is a crowd-moderated site, it's up to everybody to downvote any question that would need it. As soon as I'm the only one downvoting it, there's no problem : your question will stay on the site and answer will help others. But still I don't see any effort from your side, and your reaction comforts my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the list is in range A1 to A4

```
{=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)))*IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="MB",1/1000,IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,2)="KB",1/1000000,1)))}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm after creating an extra (IF) for Bytes. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use elegant trick with 10 power by [Dave Bruns](https://exceljet.net/formula/normalize-size-units-to-gigabytes):

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/10^((MATCH(RIGHT(A1,2),{"PB","TB","GB","MB","KB"},0)-3)*3)
```

If you are using Excel on Mac then you need to replace "," by ";" (thanks to @pokkie):

```
=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-2)/10^((MATCH(RIGHT(A1;2);{"PB";"TB";"GB";"MB";"KB"};0)-3)*3)
```

You will also have to search and replace any values such as `1.2GB` with `1,2GB`

Comment: I find yours the most general and elegant answer- up-voted!

Comment: I too much prefer this. NB On Excel Mac v. 16.78 the commas version worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Text to Columns with space as the delimiter and:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"GB",A:A)+SUMIF(B:B,"MB",A:A)/1000+SUMIF(B:B,"KB",A:A)/1000000
```

may suit.

Comment: It should be 1024 instead of 1000 and 1024/1024 instead of 1000000 for correct conversion between GB/MB/KB. Besides my Excel requires ';' as argument separator (could be different for other Excel versions though)

Comment: So it depends on definition used. Didn't know that, always thought GB/MB/KB conversion was done based on 2 to the n-th power.

Comment: Worked like a charm after setting the Value types in a different Column and setting another sumif for Bytes, thanks! :-)