# How do you add values in excel column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel column is not adding up at all and I am using O365. Any ideas?

[image: Excel not autosuming]

Comment: That's text, not numbers. Perhaps `=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(D4:D7,LEN(D4:D7)-2))`.

Comment: While keeping in mind that 512MB and 1GB as per comment above will sum to 513. Either way do not sum text.

Comment: Hi BigBen   Thanks for your help but I get errors when I try your formula. It says the following :   There is a problem with this formula, Not trying to type a formula?

Comment: Is your formula separator a `;` instead of a `,`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the array formula:

```
=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(D4:D7,"GB",""))
```

or *(depending on your Locale)*:

```
=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(D4:D7;"GB";""))
```

[image]

*(some versions of Excel may not require an array-formula.)*

**EDIT#1:**

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thanks BigBen   I followed the above and now the formula is displayed on the cell and no total. I think I am missing something here? I wonder what it is.

Comment: Hi Gary Thanks for the input. I just tried it and getting the following error.   #value . I tried again and still got the formula again.

Comment: Could there be spaces in the data?  Are there other non-number characters, such as "MB"?  @Gary'sStudent's solution requires no spaces or characters other than "GB".

Answer (score 0):

Adding text to number cells makes your life much more difficult.  You may want to consider putting only numbers in the cells and formatting the numbers to look like they have the text units in them.  Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533811/how-can-i-format-bytes-a-cell-in-excel-as-kb-mb-gb-etc) for instructions.